# About Apache RewriteRule deal with Chinese characters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, escaping

Got really confused today:
I'm working on:

```
Windows NT DESKTOP-C1R460O 10.0 build 15063 (Windows 10) AMD64
Apache2.4, 
PHP 7.1.0beta3.
```

I wrote some code in .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /datang/
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's very simple and most of the time it works fine until today,
One of my client wants his website's URL looks more SEO friendly like this:

> [http://www.example.com/product/10023/产品名称](http://www.example.com/product/10023/%E4%BA%A7%E5%93%81%E5%90%8D%E7%A7%B0)

I'm sorry that I wrote some Chinese words above, it means "product name".

The thing is when the URL coming through .htaccess, some of the words in the 'product name' part like “克”, the Apache tries to do some unescaping to its own into ISO-8859-1 which it is not working properly, but some of them like "橡树" will unescape into UTF-8 which is working fine.

I don't know why, please anyone can help?

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: Ok then, I want to delete this post since no one else got interesting on it. but I thought just in case if someone got the same like me, my suggestion is: give your codes a try on another computer, server or whatever like I did. I don't know how but it works very well on remote server.......